# Add multiple different complex icons AND info boxes to google maps api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a site for some holiday accommodation (it's my first site development).

I've been working on the location page with google maps api V3 and want to take it further. At the moment I have just two custom markers - but want to extend this so I have around 20, to show various things to do in the area. These will be divided into categories such as 'family' and 'shopping', each category having a different marker icon. So I will need say 5 different icon styles, each style at around 4 different locations. On top of this I will need an info box on each, which will popup when the marker is clicked, and will disappear when another marker is clicked.

I'm brand new to javascript and it still looks very complicated to me, so if anyone can explain how to do this it would be greatly appreciated. Current code below, and how it currently looks is here: http://www.upthorpelodges.co.uk/test/location.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.316, 0.901),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

setMarkers(map, lodge);
}

var lodge = [
  ['Lodges', 52.316, 0.901],
  ['Other', 52, 1],
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {

var image = {
    url: 'http://s20.postimg.org/kq92v5uqh/homepin.png',


 size: new google.maps.Size(32, 45),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 45)
  };

  var shadow = {
    url: 'http://s20.postimg.org/65s00bzrt/homepin_shadow.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(36, 23),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(4, 23)
  };


var shape = {
      coord: [16, 0, 0, 16, 16, 45, 32 , 16],
      type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var lodge = locations[i];

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lodge[1], lodge[2]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: lodge[0],
        zIndex: lodge[3]
    });
}
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a json object of json objects where you keep your custom images. Something like this

```
customImgObj = {
    'family'  : {'image' : YOUR_IMAGE_GOES_HERE, 'shadow' : YOUR_SHADOW_GOES_HERE},
    'couples' : {'image' : YOUR_IMAGE_GOES_HERE, 'shadow' : YOUR_SHADOW_GOES_HERE},
    'other'   : {'image' : YOUR_IMAGE_GOES_HERE, 'shadow' : YOUR_SHADOW_GOES_HERE}
};
```

Then you have your locations array where you keep one extra element, which is the type of marker.

```
var locations = [
  ['Lodges', 52.316, 0.901, 'family'],
  ['Other', 52, 1, 'couples']
];
```

And you access it like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var lodge = locations[i];

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lodge[1], lodge[2]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: customImgObj[lodge[3]].shadow,
        icon: customImgObj[lodge[3]].image,
        shape: shape,
        title: lodge[0],
        zIndex: lodge[3]  //<--- where do you keep this? In your locations array there are only three element (0, 1, 2)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm just not sure how to integrate this into my existing code? and what I should keep and remove from what I currently have. Also will this allow for adding info windows?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with creating a list of images object, and added an extra element to each array that names the type of image to load from that list object, I also added the lines of code to add an info box

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.7836, 144.580),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);

    setMarkers(map, lodge);
}

var lodge = [
  ['First marker', -37.7836, 144.580, 4, 'two'],
  ['Second marker', -37.8136, 144.590, 5, 'one'],
  ['Third marker', -37.9456, 144.600, 3, 'three'],
  ['Fourth marker', -37.9234, 144.580, 2, 'four'],
  ['Fifth marker', -37.8136, 144.610, 1, 'five']
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {

    var imageList = {};

    imageList['one'] = {
        url: 'images/number_0.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
    };
    imageList['two'] = {
        url: 'images/number_1.png',

        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
    };
    imageList['three'] = {
        url: 'images/number_2.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
    };
    imageList['four'] = {
        url: 'images/number_3.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
    };
    imageList['five'] = {
        url: 'images/number_4.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
     };

     var shape = {
         coord: [16, 0, 0, 16, 16, 45, 32 , 16],
         type: 'poly'
     };

     var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Start </h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>Editable on hover</b></p>'+
         '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
         '</div>'+
         '</div>';

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: contentString
     });

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var lodge = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lodge[1], lodge[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: imageList[lodge[4]],
            shape: shape,
            title: lodge[0],
            zIndex: lodge[3]
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```